# Regular expressions matching several values same group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a JSON file with this value as an array:

```
"role":["ONE ROLE","ROLE TWO","ROLE WHATEVER",13123,123123]
```

And I'm trying to extract all the values of the role using a regex, for dynamically getting the field "role" and all it's values within the array.

Up to now, with this regex, I've manage to extract dynamically all the data within the JSON file, however, when it reaches the array, it just extracts the first value...

```
\"(\w+)\"\:[\s\[]*\"([^\"|\,|\]]+)
```

Is there a way of repeating this capture group for all the values? If I just use the second capture group `([^\"|\,|\]]+)` I got all the fields.

I've tried this approach:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

Using the recommended `\"(?<field>\w+)\"\:[\s\[]*\"!((?:[^\"|\,|\]]+)+)!` but without any luck.

Any ideas over here?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please consider using a JSON parser to extract values from a JSON string. I do not parse JSON with regex, personally.

Comment: You "cannot" repeat a capturing group. Technically, you can, but It will just store the last value (see: https://regex101.com/r/ZGXk0b/1/). One way to solve this problem could be to capture all the content of the array (from `[` to `]`) and then programmatically, split the content by `,`. Of course, with this you must take care of `,` that could exist inside the values. Int he end... using a JSON parser will make your life easier

Comment: Thank you for your answers friends.
@WiktorStribiżew I can't use a JSON parser because I'm doing this in Splunk. The JSON data comes as a "payload" field and I need to do this using regex because I need this fields at search time, for searching within this values later in Splunk.

Julio I thought about this approach but it wouldn't work for later search on my Splunk instance. Anyhow, I'll try it.

Thank you both for your answers

Comment: [*Spath is your friend if you want automatic field extraction during search time for both XML and JSON type of data*](https://answers.splunk.com/answers/367968/how-to-parse-json-data-at-search-time.html)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the thing here is that I need the regex to make a transforms.conf for getting all the JSON fields at search time, so I'm able to search directly on Splunk at the begining, before the first pipe. I'm already using spath in other scenarios and it's great, but with spath I can't do this at the begining, for making the extraction at search time.
Anyhow, thank you very much for your answer!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty, but will do what you want.

Basically we want to 'manually' repeat the pattern `(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?` more times than you expect to find elements in the "role" array, to catch possible `","next text`.

The regex:

```
\"(\w+)\"\:[\s+\[]*\"([^\"|\,|\]]+)(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FxoGO9/4)

In javascript:

```js
let regex = /\"(\w+)\"\:[\s+\[]*\"([^\"|\,|\]]+)(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?(?:"?,"?)?([^\"|\,|\]]+)?/

let json = '"role":["ONE ROLE","ROLE TWO","ROLE WHATEVER",13123,123123]';

let match = json.match(regex);

match = match.slice(2); //extract roles
match = match.filter(Boolean); //filter out undefined

console.log(match);
/*
[
  "ONE ROLE",
  "ROLE TWO",
  "ROLE WHATEVER",
  "13123",
  "123123"
] */
```

Comment: What if the array has more than 8 elements?

Comment: Well I did say above you need to repeat it more times than you'd expect there to be elements... I also did say it's not pretty :(

Comment: thanks for the answer @chatnoir, but this approach wouldn't help since the size of the array will be dynamic. In my example we had 5 elements, but it can be more than that.